# Windows 10 File Explorer doesn't open any drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a Windows 10 PC and when I open File Explorer it just opens the window. When I want to open any drive (any hdd or sdd) is does nothing. In the address bar you can see that is loading but nothing happens.

Edit
@Scott

(3) System is on SDD, data is on HDD

(5) I can run programs

(6) I can run cmd and all commands

Comment: I assume you have tried to reboot the machine?  Have you tried Safe Mode?  A malfunctioning storage device could cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: (1) You say ‘‘It is just opening’’, so I guess a window is appearing.  What does it look like?  (Can you post a screenshot?  Even if you can, *also* describe what you see.)  (2) How long have you waited for it to do something?  (3) Is your system drive an HDD or an SSD?  (4) Is there any indication that it is accessing the drive?  (Can you run Resource Monitor?  In the case of an HDD, can you hear any mechanical sounds?)  (5) Can you run programs? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you run a program such as Notepad, WordPad, Paint, a browser, a Microsoft Office (or LibreOffice) program, etc., if you do “Open” or “Save As”, do you get a dialog box that lets you navigate the file system?  (6) If you can run CMD (Command Prompt) or PowerShell, what do `cd` and `dir` (etc.) tell you? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two levels of repairs you can run.

**One:**

**Run DISM and SFC:**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

See if this repair works. If not, proceed to number 2

**Two:**

**Run a Windows 10 Repair Install**

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

Take note of the 3 ways (increasing error problem) and start with Keep Everything.

> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Method One or Two should work.

Comment: For now step1 did the trick

Comment: Thanks for the update. Step 2 may be helpful for others or at a later time.